# Mongoose, array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose, reactjs

Update:
This problem seems to be related to mongoose. Please see update at the bottom.

In the parent I use the following code to pass `choosenItem` to a grandChild:

```
childContextTypes: {
        foo: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
         },

   getChildContext: function() {
        return { foo: this.state.choosenDriver }
   },
```

choosenDriver is a `mongoose` Model that looks like this:

```
var Schema    = mongoose.Schema;
var driverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  driver: String,
  age: String,
  cars: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Driver', driverSchema);
```

This works fine and in the GrandChild I can do the following:

```
contextTypes: {
      foo: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  },

//some other stuff...

render: function(){
  return (
            <h1>{this.context.foo.name}</h1>
          )
});
```

And this displays the name of the `choosenDriver`.

I would also like to loop through the cars and thought it could be done like this:

```
render: function(){

   var cars = new Array(this.context.foo.cars);
   var driversCars = cars.map(function(car,i){
   return <li key={i}> {car} </li>;
   });
  return (
         <div>
            <h1>{this.context.foo.name}</h1>
            <ul>{driversCars}</ul>
         </div>

  )
}

 });
```

This returns all the drivers cars in a string displayed on one single line.
I took a look in react developers tool and saw that cars is not defined as an Array.

Is this maybe because `choosenDriver` is a `state` and arrays are not supported in this manner?

The cars obviously exists but not as an Array.

Any ideas on how to access cars as an Array in this example?

Thank you!

Update:

When looking at this.context.foo.cars in react-Tools i see this:

```
cars: 
->_proto_ :{..} 
0: "4242594395935934", 
1: "3543435095340509"
etc...

cars should be an Array so I would expect to see:
cars: Array[4]
```

Allthough in the DB everythingg looks as it should:

```
"cars":["5607b0747eb3eefc225aed61","5607b07a7eb3eefc225aed62","5606bf4b0e76916c1d1668b4","5607b07a7eb3eefc225aed62"]}]
```

Last Update:
Here they are next to eachother i react Tools:
(I have a list of drivers and this shows that the Driver-object Changes when it gets selected)

```
State:
choosenDriver: {..}
 _v:0
 _id: "235345353453"
 name: "Roger"
 cars: 
    ->_proto_ :{..} 
    0: "4242594395935934", 
   _id: undefined 


Same driver but not choosen:
drivers: array[3]
 ->0: {}
 ->1: {}
      _v: 0
      _id: "4242594395935934"
      cars: Array[1]
```

So something happens to the Array when it gets selected. Weird...

Comment: React object can handle arrays in their state without a problem, maybe you could add the moongose tag to this questions, I'm pretty sure the problem is there.

Comment: Do you mean `cars` is not an Array or `this.context.foo.cars` is not an Array?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `cars` is not the Array you expect (and not `this.context.foo.cars`)...

The Array constructor builds an array with each argument to the constructor as an element in the returned array.

So, `new Array([1,2,3])` gives you: `[[1,2,3]]`.

You want `Array.from([1,2,3])` which will give you `[1,2,3]` which appears to be what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

But with your code, why can't you just skip creating the intermediate array and just call `this.context.foo.cars.map(...)` directly?

Comment: Yes, this.context.foo.cars.map(...)  was my first attempt but it returns:
cannot read property 'map' of undefined. So I guess the cars is not a 'proper' Array as the comment above suggests.

Comment: Ok, this answer doesnt really apply then - but I'll leave it because the fact that `this.context.foo.cars` is `undefined` and not something else is hugely relevant to your question - you should update with that detail and then I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question to better reflect the actual problem.

Comment: did you try `var driversCars = [];this.context.foo.cars.forEach(function(car) { driverCars.push(<li key={i}> {car} </li>);})`. Looks like mongoosejs offers a foreach: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.7.x/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Collection

Comment: Thank you, but this returns cannot read property 'foreach' of undefined, I Think I must have made a mistake createing the Array in mongoose given that cars appearently is not an Array. But I thank you.